# Working fine in browser.But collapse when minimize or resizing the browser

Tags: jquery, css, html

```
    I have written  code using HTML and CSS. It is working fine in browser but when I minimize or change the size of browser design collapses. Kindly help.

    Here is the code. The class which I am using.

        .container {
            position: relative;
            top: 100px;
            left: 100px;
            float: left;
            width: 100%;
         }


    This is for first dot:

         #first {
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            border: 1px solid #000;
            border-radius: 25px;
            float: left;
         }

    For second dot:

         #second {
            width: 7.5%;
            height: 30px;
            float: left;
            border-bottom: 1px solid;
            border-top: 1px solid;
            position: relative;
            top: 10px;
            margin-left: -6px;
            background: white;
         }

    For third dot:

         #three {
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            border: 1px solid #000;
            border-radius: 25px;
            float: left;
            margin-left: -5px;
         }

    This is for fourth dot:

         #four {
            width: 7.5%;
            height: 30px;
            float: left;
            border-bottom: 1px solid;
            border-top: 1px solid;
            position: relative;
            top: 10px;
            margin-left: -6px;
            background: white;
         }
         #five {
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            border: 1px solid #000;
            border-radius: 25px;
            float: left;
            margin-left: -5px;
         }
         #six {
            width: 3.5%;
            height: 30px;
            float: left;
            border-bottom: 1px solid;
            border-top: 1px solid;
            position: relative;
            top: 10px;
            margin-left: -6px;
            background: white;
         }
         #seven {
            width: 7%;
            height: 30px;
            float: left;
            border-bottom: 1px solid;
            border-top: 1px solid;
            position: relative;
            top: -15px;
            margin-left: 1px;
            background: white;
            -webkit-transform: rotate(-30deg);
            -ms-transform: rotate(-30deg);
            -moz-transform: rotate(-30deg);
            -o-transform: rotate(-30deg);
            transform: rotate(-30deg);
            z-index: 9;
         }
         #eight {
            width: 7%;
            height: 30px;
            float: left;
            border-bottom: 1px solid;
            border-top: 1px solid;
            position: relative;
            top: 36px;
            margin-left: -93px;
            background: white;
            -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
            -ms-transform: rotate(30deg);
            -moz-transform: rotate(30deg);
            -o-transform: rotate(30deg);
            transform: rotate(30deg);
            z-index: 8;
         }
         #nine {
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            border: 1px solid #000;
            border-radius: 25px;
            float: left;
            position: relative;
            top: -58px;
            right: 18px;
         }
         #ten {
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            border: 1px solid #000;
            border-radius: 25px;
            float: left;
            position: relative;
            top: 60px;
            right: 67px;
         }
         .name {
            float: left;
            top: 60px;
            position: relative;
         }
         .new {
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            background: white;
            position: absolute;
            left: 393px;
            top: 18px;
            z-index: 10;
         }
         .first_inside {
            position: absolute;
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            background: #000;
            top: 15px;
            left: 15px;
            border-radius: 15px;
            display: none;
         }
         .second_inside {
            position: absolute;
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            background: #000;
            top: 15px;
            left: 11.6%;
            border-radius: 15px;
            display: none; 
         }
         .third_inside {
            position: absolute;
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            background: #000;
            top: 15px;
            left: 22.2%;
            border-radius: 15px;
            display: none; 
            z-index: 15;
         }
         .four_inside {
            position: absolute;
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            background: #000;
            top: 15px;
            left: 15px;
            border-radius: 15px;
            display: none; 
         }
         .five_inside {
            position: absolute;
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            background: #000;
            top: 15px;
            left: 15px;
            border-radius: 15px;
            display: none; 
         }
         #connet_first_second {
            position: absolute;
            width: 10%;
            border: 1px solid;
            left: 2%;
            top: 23px;
            display: none;
         }
         #connet_second_third {
            position: absolute;
            width: 11%;
            border: 1px solid;
            left: 170px;
            top: 23px;
            display: none;
         }
         #connet_third_four_one {
            position: absolute;
            width: 6%;
            border: 1px solid;
            left: 23%;
            top: 22px;
            display: none;
            z-index: 11;
         }
         #connet_third_four_second {
            position: absolute;
            width: 7.5%;
            border: 1px solid;
            left: 28.5%;
            top: -4px;
            display: none;
            z-index: 11;
            -webkit-transform: rotate(-30deg);
            -ms-transform: rotate(-30deg);
            -o-transform: rotate(-30deg);
            -moz-transform: rotate(-30deg);
            transform: rotate(-30deg);
         }
          #connet_third_four_new {
            position: absolute;
            width: 5.5%;
            border: 1px solid;
            left: 23%;
            top: 26px;
            display: none;
            z-index: 11;
         }
          #connet_four_five {
            position: absolute;
            width: 8.5%;
            border: 1px solid;
            left: 28%;
            top: 55px;
            display: none;
            z-index: 11;
            -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
            -ms-transform: rotate(30deg);
            -o-transform: rotate(30deg);
            -moz-transform: rotate(30deg);
            transform: rotate(30deg);
         }


    All the dots are connected as a pipeline and all is running fine too, but on minimizing the window things are collapsing.



    Here is the HTML code:-
    This is the html code in which i am using css as mentioned above.
    Kindly review and suggest something.
    It is working fine in browser but while minimizing all thing collapses.




    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        /*$("#first").click(function(){
            mystatus('OPENED');
            return false;
        });*/

        var status = '';

        status = 'RETURNED';

        if(status == 'RETURNED'){
            mystatus(status,'true');
        }

        function mystatus(input, string){
            status = ''+input+'';

            $(".first_inside").hide();
            $(".second_inside").hide();
            $("#connet_first_second").hide();
            $(".third_inside").hide();
            $("#connet_second_third").hide();
            $(".four_inside").hide();
            $(".five_inside").hide();
            $("#connet_third_four_one").hide();
            $("#connet_third_four_second").hide();
            $("#connet_four_five").hide();
            $("#connet_third_four_new").hide();

            if(status == 'OPENED') {
                $(".first_inside").show();
                $("#three").click(function(){
                    mystatus('INPROGRESS','false');
                    return false;
                });
                $("#first").unbind('click');
            }else if(status == 'INPROGRESS'){
                $(".first_inside").show();
                $(".second_inside").show();
                $("#connet_first_second").show();
                if(string == 'true'){
                    $("#five").click(function(){
                        mystatus('COMPLETED','false');
                        return false;
                    });
                }
                $("#first").unbind('click');
                $("#three").unbind('click');
                $("#nine").unbind('click');
            }else if(status == 'COMPLETED'){
                $(".first_inside").show();
                $(".second_inside").show();
                $("#connet_first_second").show();
                $(".third_inside").show();
                $("#connet_second_third").show();
                $(".third_inside").css({'background':'#000','border':'1px solid'});
                if(string == 'true'){
                    $("#nine").click(function(){
                        mystatus('CLOSED','false');
                        return false;
                    });
                    $("#ten").click(function(){
                        mystatus('RETURNED','false');
                        return false;
                    });
                }
                $("#first").unbind('click');
                $("#three").unbind('click');
                $("#five").unbind('click');
            }else if(status == 'CLOSED'){
                $(".first_inside").show();
                $(".second_inside").show();
                $("#connet_first_second").show();
                $(".third_inside").show();
                $("#connet_second_third").show();
                $(".four_inside").show();
                $("#connet_third_four_one").show();
                $("#connet_third_four_second").show();
                $("#first").unbind('click');
                $("#three").unbind('click');
                $("#five").unbind('click');
                $("#ten").unbind('click');
            }
            else if(status == 'RETURNED'){
                $(".first_inside").show();
                $(".second_inside").show();
                $("#connet_first_second").show();
                $(".third_inside").show();
                $("#connet_second_third").show();
                $(".four_inside").hide();
                $(".five_inside").show();
                $("#connet_third_four_one").hide();
                $("#connet_third_four_second").hide();
                $("#connet_four_five").show();
                $("#connet_third_four_new").show();
                $(".third_inside").css({'background':'#fff','border':'1px solid'});
                $("#five").click(function(){
                    mystatus('COMPLETED','true');
                    return false;
                });
                $("#first").unbind('click');
                $("#three").unbind('click');
                $("#nine").unbind('click');
            }

        }
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="first"><span class="first_inside"></span><span class="name">open</span></div>
            <div id="second"></div>
            <div id="connet_first_second"></div>
            <div id="three"><span class="second_inside"></span><span class="name">In Progress</span></div>
            <div id="four"></div>
            <div id="connet_second_third"></div>
            <div id="five"><span class="third_inside"></span><span class="name">Fixed</span></div>
            <div id="six"></div>
            <div id="connet_third_four_one"></div>
            <div id="connet_third_four_new"></div>
            <div id="connet_third_four_second"></div>
            <div id="connet_four_five"></div>
            <div id="seven"></div>
            <span class="new"></span>
            <div id="eight"></div>
            <div id="nine"><span class="four_inside"></span><span class="name">Closed</span></div>
            <div id="ten"><span class="five_inside"></span><span class="name">Returned</span></div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

This is the html code in which i am using css as mentioned above.
        Kindly review and suggest something.
        It is working fine in browser but while minimizing all thing collapses.
 This is the html code in which i am using css as mentioned above.
        Kindly review and suggest something.
        It is working fine in browser but while minimizing all thing collapses.

Comment: Html is missing. Can you just put a link in http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Dont know much about jsfiddle.net but i have copied HTML

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wtjg9set/ here is the link

Comment: You just need to put the HTML, CSS & JS in the right places. and see that what your example working won the buttom right box, your CSS hav ">" at the begining of every line - this is wrong! and you need to put the JS in the right place so I can understand what is your issue

Comment: I've changed your fiddle for you because I couldn't handle it http://jsfiddle.net/wtjg9set/1/

Answer (score 0):

This is very difficult to scale and will require a lot of changes. I would suggest either:

- **Positioning the elements** Adding `position:absolute;` or `position:fixed;` to your elements and adjusting their position using `top:x; left: x;` so they're in a fixed position on the page.
- **Using SVG** Changing the whole thing to be done with **SVG**. Although a large task to redo it, it would probably be the best way and could be drawn with graphics software (e.g. Inkscape or Adobe Illustrator).

Try resizing the results window here http://jsfiddle.net/wtjg9set/1/ and you will notice that the result only currently works at a particular size.